# Jquery nth child value not returned with each function

Tags: php, jquery, html

Below is the code i used. I have 2 sets of list boxes. If skill1 is selected then expertise1 should be selected. Similarly if skill 2 is selected then expertise2 should be selected.

HTMl listbox code

```
<select size="1" name="prev_specific_function[0][]" id="prev_specific_function" >
    <option value=""> skills</option>
    <option value="1"> skills1</option>
    <option value="2"> skills2</option>
    <option value="3"> skills3</option>
    <!-- -->
</select>

<select size="1" name="prev_function_expertise[0][]" id="prev_function_expertise" tabindex="18">
    <option value="">expertise1</option>
    <option value="6">exp 1 </option>
    <option value="5">exp  2 </option>
    <option value="3">exp  3 </option>
    <option value="2">exp 4 </option>

</select><br>
<br>
<br>

<select size="1" name="prev_specific_function[0][]" id="prev_specific_function" >
    <option value=""> skills2</option>
    <option value="1"> skills1</option>
    <option value="2"> skills2</option>
    <option value="3"> skills3</option>
    <!-- -->
</select>

<select size="1" name="prev_function_expertise[0][]" id="prev_function_expertise" tabindex="18">
    <option value="">expertise2</option>
    <option value="6">exp 1 </option>
    <option value="5">exp  2 </option>
    <option value="3">exp  3 </option>
    <option value="2">exp 4 </option>
</select>
```

Jquery function i used is

```
$("select[name^='prev_specific_function']").each(function( i ) {
    lsval = this.value;

    if(lsval != '') {
        cld =  $("select[name^='prev_function_expertise']:nth-child("+i+")").val();
        alert('CLD: '+cld);
    }
});
```

Here i couldnt get the expertise list box value. The cld variable is returned as undefined.  What i am doing wrong. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following Line

```
$("select[name^='prev_specific_function']").each(function( i ) {
    lsval = this.value;

    if(lsval != '') {

         cld =  $("select[name^='prev_function_expertise']").eq(i).val();
        alert('CLD: '+cld);


    }

});
```

Hope that will help